# Redux updateElementSaga has been cancelled. Why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I just implemented a drag and drop feature with react-dnd and when the user drops the `SkyElement` item in my app, I update `top` and `left` on the server which in turn updates the redux store

However, the update call works occasionally, not every time. And in my console, I see a warning; `updateElementSaga has been cancelled`

In my `SlotView.js`, in a function, I have:

`this.props.dispatch(requestUpdateElement({ id, top, left }));`

In my `elements/actions.js`:

```
export function requestUpdateElement(element) {
    return { type: 'requestUpdateElement', element };
}
```

In my `elements/sagas.js`:

```
export function *updateElementSaga(action) {
    const response = yield call(api.updateElement, action.element);

    if (response.element) {
        // debugger; // this hits, saga was cancelled will have appeared in the console at this point
        yield put(actions.receiveElement(response.element));
    } else if (response.error) {
        console.log('error receiving element');
    }
}

export default [
    takeLatest('requestUpdateElement', updateElementSaga),
];
```

In `api.js`:

```
export function updateElement(element) {
    const userId = JSON.parse(localStorage.cookies).userId;
    element.userId = userId;

    if (userId) {
        return apiHelper.put(
            `${apiHelper.getBaseUrl()}/users/${element.userId}/elements/${element.id}`,
            {element},
            {headers: apiHelper.getHeaders()}
        ).catch((error) => {
            return {error};
        });
    } else {
        console.log('user ID could not be found for request');
    }
}
```

And my `elements/reducer.js`:

```
const defaultState = {
    elementsMap: {},
    visibleElements: [],
    unplacedElements: [],
};

export default function(state = defaultState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'receiveElement':
            let element = null;
            let unplacedElement = null;

            if (action.element.sectorId === undefined) {
                unplacedElement = `${action.element.id}`;
            } else {
                element = `${action.element.id}`;

                // don't add, duplicate
                const newState = {...state}; // copy old state
                delete newState[`${action.element.id}`]; // delete the item from the object
                const newVisibleElements = newState.visibleElements.filter(e => e !== `${action.element.id}`); // remove item from visible elements
                const newUnplacedElements = newState.unplacedElements.filter(e => e !== `${action.element.id}`);

                return {
                    ...newState,
                    elementsMap: {
                        ...newState.elementsMap,
                        [element]: action.element,
                    },
                    visibleElements: [...newVisibleElements, element],
                    unplacedElements: [...newUnplacedElements],
                };
            }

            return {
                ...state,
                elementsMap: {
                    ...state.elementsMap,
                    [action.element.id]: action.element,
                },
                visibleElements: [...state.visibleElements, element],
                unplacedElements: [...state.unplacedElements, unplacedElement],
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Like I mentioned before, sometimes the update works, but not every time. I've narrowed the problem down to the client. Server seems to be acting fine. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: can you share `receiveElement ` function ?

Comment: From my `/elements/actions.js`: `export function receiveElement(element) {
    return { type: 'receiveElement', element };`
}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using `takeLatest` the redux saga documentation does mention:

https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/basics/UsingSagaHelpers.html

> Unlike takeEvery, **takeLatest** allows only one fetchData task to run at
>   any moment.  And it will be the latest started task.  If a previous
>   task is still running when another fetchData task is started,  **the
>   previous task will be automatically cancelled**.

Where `fetchData` is the generator function that is being served using `takeLatest` or `takeEvery`

And when your UI keeps invoking the same action, before it gets completed, it will keep cancelling 
the last invoked action, and hence you would keep getting the message intermittently:

`updateElementSaga has been cancelled`

Which by nature `takeLatest` is doing the right thing. Which is:

> `Always take the latest invoked action`

In case you want every action to be caught and processed, do use `takeEvery`, as:

```
export default [
    takeEvery('requestUpdateElement', updateElementSaga),
];
```